# Levenshtein module in python doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, levenshtein-distance

I installed the module python-Levenshtein-0.11.2. I think the setup succeeded (when I type `help('modules')`, I see "Levenshtein" module in the list).

But when I tried the "distance" function, I got this error:    `"NameError: name 'distance' is not defined"`.

I can't understand why the distance function doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you are importing the correct module?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using? (Including import statement).

Comment: What does `import Levenshtein; print Levenshtein` show is imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not forgetting to use the module namespace are you?

Calls should look something like this:

```
import Levenshtein
lev_dist = Levenshtein.distance(args)
```

Alternatively, you can make `distance()` accessible without the `module.` bit by doing:

```
from Levenshtein import distance
lev_dist = distance(args)
```

Comment: This might be useful too: [Python tutorial - modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Thanks! I'm new at this and forget i need to use the module namespace. Thanks again.